# Add datetime difference to a duplicate selection

Tags: sql

The below sql gives me a list of CustomerID and FeeRuleID where there are duplicated records. The problem is, that I need to make sure the output of this is only "true" duplicates - those created within one second of each other.

How do I add the requirement in of `Having count()>1 AND cfr.ModifiedOn difference <1 second`?

```
select cfr.CustomerID, cfr.FeeRuleID
FROM CustomerFeeRule cfr
       inner join FeeRule fr on cfr.FeeRuleID = fr.FeeRuleID
       inner join FeeType ft on fr.FeeTypeID = ft.FeeTypeID
where GetDate() BETWEEN cfr.DateEffective and cfr.DateTerminated
group by cfr.CustomerID, cfr.FeeRuleID
having count(cfr.CustomerID)>1
Order by cfr.CustomerID, cfr.FeeRuleID
```

DateEffective is in the format `date`
ModifiedOn is in the format `datetime`

Comment: Convert `ModifiedOn` to  `SMALLDATETIME` and add it to the `GROUP BY`

Comment: If you had 3 records (A, B, C) with the same CustomerID/FeeRuleID, A/B modifiedOn difference < 1 and B/C modifiedOn difference < 1 but A/C modifiedOn difference > 1 then how would you handle this?